# Delphi: create menu (tabs) like in FineReader 11

Tags: delphi, menu, custom-controls, finereader

Can I create a menu like in Fine Reader 11 in Delphi XE (also using 3d party controls)? What do I need to make an effect like on pictures below? Thanks.

[image]

Some other examples:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: crate == box, therefore, this is menu-box, right?

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with using normal buttons(aligned top) on a panel(aligned left), it's much better than giving your application a "bloatware"-feel, spend time on making your application better.

Comment: Some people like to use a more "shiny" look and feel.  Personally I find all of the above as appealing as brown shoes with a tuxedo, but I recognize that many people like fruity colors, or shiny carbon-fibre reinforced gray UIs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TMS have a similar menu in their [Advanced Toolbars & Menus](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advtoolbar.asp) components

**UPDATE:**

TMS Advanced Toolbars & Menus include [TAdvPolyMenu](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advpolylist.asp), which you can customize as your preferred style.
[image]

Comment: is that menu only for a ribbon?

Comment: @maxfax, No, You can use TAdvPolyMenu to create the same effect without using RibbonBar, Look at the image above.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [AdvOfficePager](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/aop.asp) from Tms Components : 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get some very similar results using the JvNavPanel controls in the Jedi JVCL component set.

Comment: and how can I archive that effect? Please see more examples in my question.

Comment: Your question is now so vague as to be unanswerable.